# JavaScript dependency injection using RequireJS, Jasmine and testr

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, requirejs, jasmine

I've just looking for dependency injection in my unit test strategy using RequireJS and Jasmine. I really like the idea behind [testr](https://github.com/mattfysh/testr.js) and I have tried to setup testr following the examples in github but I can't figure out what is wrong. I always get the error

> Error: module has not been loaded: **today**

when testr tries to load the module that is going to be tested.

Here some context..

**index.html**
..

```
<script data-main="config" src="../../assets/js/libs/require.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/testr.js"></script>
```

**config.js**
..

```
require.config({

  // Initialize specs.
  deps:["main"],
...
...
});
```

**main.js**
..

```
require([
  // Load the example spec, replace this and add your own spec
  "spec/today"
], function() {
  var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();
  jasmineEnv.execute();
});
```

**spec\today.js**
..

```
describe('Today print', function() {
  var date = {}, today;
  beforeEach(function() {
     date.today = new Date(2012, 3, 30);
     today = testr('today', {'util/date': date});  //Here is where the error is thrown
  });

  it('is user-friendly', function() {
     expect(today.getDateString()).toBe('Today is Monday, 30th April, 2012');
  });
});
```

**today.js**
..

```
define(['string', 'util/date'], function(string, date) {
  return {
    getDateString: function() {
      return string.format('Today is %d', date.today);
    }
  }
});
```

Is there anybody that have been with the same kind of trouble? . I'm using RequireJS 2.0.6

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'today' module needs to be loaded from requirejs before you use it with testr.
Try something like:

```
require(['today'], function(){
    describe('Today print', function() {
      var date = {}, today;
      beforeEach(function() {
         date.today = new Date(2012, 3, 30);
         today = testr('today', {'util/date': date});  //Here is where the error is thrown
      });

      it('is user-friendly', function() {
         expect(today.getDateString()).toBe('Today is Monday, 30th April, 2012');
      });
    });
});
```

Also read: http://cyberasylum.janithw.com/mocking-requirejs-dependencies-for-unit-testing/

Comment: okay. i've been working on getting testr working for a few days straight now. This is the closest i've come to seeing an example project. I've created a github repo for this example (with some minor tweaks) using jasmine to share with others. However, it is still not working. Can anyone help out here? Thanks.

https://github.com/loesak/jasmine-maven-require-testr

Comment: I am having the same problem. In fact, I manually load it as a dep in my require.config, and Karma shows that the file is getting requested (first).